# What date is used in an Atom document's updated element?

Tags: date, atom-feed

I have an Atom document where the atom:updated element date is that of the request made to the server. Therefore it changes on each request.

My initial thoughts were that this was incorrect and would prefer to use the date of the latest published item.

So I checked the [Atom documentation for atom:updated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-4.2.15):

> The "atom:updated" element is a Date construct indicating the most recent instant in time when an entry or feed was modified in a way the publisher considers significant. Therefore, not all modifications necessarily result in a changed atom:updated value.
> atomUpdated = element atom:updated { atomDateConstruct }.
> Publishers MAY change the value of this element over time.

I believe this backs-up my thoughts, but maybe there is a case for using the request date in certain circumstances too.

So what date is used in atom:updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what date is used in atom:updated?

The specification you cite seems to answer that question:

> The "atom:updated" element is a Date construct indicating the most recent instant in time when an entry or feed was modified in a way the publisher considers significant.

As a publisher, if you consider the document to be under constant significant modification then it would be compliant with the specification to return the current time.

However, it's more likely that consumers would expect that date's change to reflect specific changes.

Comment: Thanks Joe, you've helped me be crystal clear on this now. Returning the current time is just something that happens at the moment. It is completely independent of any modification so not even a question of significant change. In this case I need to get atom:updated changed to be the latest published date of the enclosed items, as this makes the most sense as publisher and what the consumer would expect. Awesome!